# Interactive Pyvis Diagram Search function

Tags: python, html, graph, networkx, pyvis

Hi i am creating an interactive graph in Pyvis with more than 200 nodes and i want to add a search bar functionality, so i can have the chance to add in the search bar the node name and that it will be selected in the graph.

Does anyone had anything like this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a sufficient solution?

Answer (score 2):

I am currently working on the same thing. One tool I have used in the past is a software called Gephi. It allows you to load in a node and edges table which can then be displayed in an html through sigma.js. If you find anything for pyvis let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually i am working with Python, so i need something that it could be automated and therefore i need to add my input information in Python and maybe use Gephi through an API to create the visualization. For Pyvis my idea is to write a function in the HTML generated file using CGI library and through a dictionary to have the results.